# Converting Epoch time to UTC

Tags: c#, utc

I thought that the Unix epoch was already in UTC, but if so, why does calling `ToUniversalTime()` on it change it's value.

Example code (the real values originally come from a JSON file)

```
var ms = 1655494371419 ;
var ds = "2022-06-17T19:32:51.419Z" ;

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(ds));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(ds).ToUniversalTime());
    
Console.WriteLine(System.DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(ms).DateTime);
Console.WriteLine(System.DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(ms).DateTime.ToUniversalTime());
```

produces

```
17/06/2022 20:32:51
17/06/2022 19:32:51
17/06/2022 19:32:51
17/06/2022 18:32:51
```

I'm based in the UK and currently on BST.

Is `System.DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(ms).DateTime)` not the best way to convert epoch time?

Comment: Does this make sense? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.datetime?view=net-6.0#remarks

Comment: What datatype (and offset value) do you want as a result?

Comment: So even though DateTimeOffset knows what offset it is using (which is 0) , calling DateTime **deliberately** ignores the offset and returns a DateTime with DateTimeKind. Unspecified and I'm guessing that `ToUniversalTime()` treats this as if it was DateTimeKind.Local and adjusts it by an hour.

Comment: In other words, `System.DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(ms).DateTime` is **always** wrong and I need to use `System.DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(ms).UtcDateTime`

Comment: yep https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=net-6.0#remarks